# How to fix problem 'request cannot be resolved to a variable' on android?

Tags: android, http, if-statement

Have the following code:

```
if (post) {
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
    Log.i(TAG, "Posting URL: " + url);
} else {
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
    Log.i(TAG, "Getting URL: " + url);              
}

...
if (signed) {
    OAuthConsumer consumer = getConsumer(prefs);
    consumer.sign(request); // here is the error
}
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define your request outside of the `if` statement:

```
HttpRequestBase request = null;

if (post) {
    request = ...
} else {
    request = ...
}
```

otherwise your the scope of your `request` variable is limited to the body of the `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

`request` is declared inside `if (post) {..}` and again at `else{..}` so it exists only until the end of the block. To fix it, declare `request` outside the `if` block as `HttpRequestBase request = null;`, and instantiate it to the needed type in the if-else block. (both `HttpPost` and `HttpGet` extend `HttpRequestBase`.